# Как защитить sql insert от sql injection в python?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Как защитить такой insert запрос от sql инъекций ? Я использую python 3.7 и БД mysql 5.7 с библиотекой pymysql.
Вот код который надо защитить:

```
self.cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO items (res_id, log_id, link, title, content, n_date, nd_date, s_date, not_date)
                       VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''',
                       ( res_id,
                         log_id,
                         str(resource_link),
                         str(item_title),
                         str(item_content),
                         str(n_date),
                         nd_date,
                         s_date,
                         not_date
                       )
                                    )
        print('Запись новостей успешно произведена!')
```

UPD: То что я экранировал `VALUES` защитит мой `insert`?

Comment: Тут, по идеи, не нужно ничего делать -- вы ведь не вручную sql-строку составили по полям, а использовали привязку (binding)

Comment: Вы уверенны что мой sql `insert` защищен ?

Comment: Ага, а в ссылке ответа есть подтверждение этому

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, экранирование `VALUES` защищает `insert`. На [английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647301/how-do-pymysql-prevent-user-from-sql-injection-attack) есть подробное объяснение, почему.

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку !